# Android Alarm Manager service does not work

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've found a lot of solutions here about the Alarm Manager but none of them seemed to work.

I create the background service with:

```
public void scheduleSync() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SyncReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), SYNC_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Sync scheduled.");
}
```

The SyncReceiver class is:

```
public class SyncReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, WebBackendSyncService_.class);
        context.startService(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "WebBackendSyncService started.");
    }
}
```

And that is the WebBackendSyncService defined with Android Annotations:

```
@EIntentService
public class WebBackendSyncService extends IntentService {
    public static final String ACTION = "com.invoicing.networking.WebBackendSyncService";
    private static final String TAG = "WebBackendSyncService";

    @RestService
    APIService restClient;

    public WebBackendSyncService() { super(ACTION);}


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Handling sync intent.");
        sendInvoices();
    }

    @Background
    void sendInvoices() {
         SyncData.sendInvoices(restClient);
    }
}
```

Service and Broadcast receiver in the manifest:

```
<service
     android:name=".networking.WebBackendSyncService_"
     android:exported="false" />

 <receiver
     android:name=".networking.SyncReceiver"
     android:process=":remote" />
```

Looking at those line for the past couple of hours pushed me to ask for help here. I hope you'll see something that I'm missing.

Looking at the console output it gets to "Sync scheduled."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after removing unused dependencies and multi-dex config. Zero changes to the code itself, however, it works for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `<service>` element has a rogue underscore in the `android:name` attribute that you need to remove.

Second, get rid of `android:process=":remote"`. Forking a whole process for a two-line `BroadcastReceiver` is not very efficient, and it will interfere with the next fix.

Third, switch from `BroadcastReceiver` to `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and follow the instructions for using that class, as right now the device will readily fall asleep either before or during the service's work.

Comment: I have to stick with the underscore as it won't compile due to the Android Annotations. Getting rid of the `:remote` and changing to `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` hasn't helped at this point.

Comment: @drive235: "I have to stick with the underscore as it won't compile due to the Android Annotations" -- oh, yeah, sorry, missed that part. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to confirm that your alarm is scheduled. Also, monitor LogCat for warnings/errors with stack traces at the point when the alarm should be going off. You might also want to (temporarily) drop back to `targetSdkVersion` of `18` and use `setRepeating()`, as the inexactness tends to hamper debugging.

Comment: I've temporarily deleted all of the Android Annotation stuff just to see if it makes a difference - it doesn't. However, the command you recommended shows that wakeups are in the correct interval: `*walarm*:com.invoicing/.networking.SyncReceiver`

Comment: @drive235: And you're not getting anything from `SyncReceiver` itself, either in the form of your `Log.d()` call or some stack trace saying that `SyncReceiver` couldn't be instantiated or something? If so, that's bizarre, and I don't have a great answer for what's going on.

Comment: I get nothing. No logs, no stack traces. Even debugger doesn't stop in the onReceive. It might have something to do with the Annotations. Thank you for trying!

Comment: @drive235: FWIW, here is a trivial sample app that demonstrates the use of `AlarmManager` with a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast

Comment: Thank you for you example. I've copied my code to a new project (the part with SyncReceiver and WebBackendSyncService. It works flawlessly as it should.

Comment: Today I've removed the multi-dex config which I've set up due to the colossal number of methods in the dex file (too many dependencies). I've taken over the project from a colleague and I haven't checked all the libs he used. Now the project is cleaned and compiled with a sigle dex. Everything works now.

Comment: @drive235: I'm not quite sure why multidex would have caused a problem here, but I'm glad it's working now for you!